# OrientDB disk utilization

Tags: orientdb

I have been working with orientDB and stored about 120 Million records to it, the size on disk was 24 GB, I then I deleted all the records by running the following commands against console :

```
Delete from E unsafe
Delete from V unsafe
```

When i checked the DB size on disk it was also 24 GB, Is there anything extra I need to do to get free disk space?

Comment: Anyway internally the space is reclaimed, so if you create new records, the space is re-used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In OrientDB when you delete a record the disk space remains allocated. The only way to free it is to export than re-import the DB.

Comment: The suggested edits queue is full at this time and I can't edit your question, so I'll leave this info as a comment here: the source for this information is OrientDB's documentation on the disk storage engine at https://orientdb.org/docs/3.0.x/internals/Paginated-Local-Storage.html.